# Coherence Servers Weblogic 12.1.1 ClassNotFoundException

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, oracle-coherence

I am following a tutorial and in some part I need set some parameter in Server Start on the Coherence Servers.

My Class Path configurations are:

```
/opt/Oracle/Weblogic/12.1.1/coherence_3.7/lib/coherence.jar:
/opt/Oracle/Weblogic/12.1.1/modules/javax.management_1.2.2.jar:
/opt/Oracle/Weblogic/12.1.1/modules/javax.management.remote_1.0.1.4.jar:
/opt/Oracle/Weblogic/12.1.1/coherence_3.7/lib/coherence-web-spi.war:`
```

and my Argument configurations are:

```
-Dtangosol.coherence.management.remote=true
-Dtangosol.coherence.management=all
-Dtangosol.coherence.session.localstorage=true
-Dtangosol.coherence.cacheconfig=/opt/Oracle/Weblogic/12.1.1/user_projects/domains/labs_domain/config/coherence/my_coh_cluster/session-cache-config.xml
‐Xmanagement:autodiscovery=false,authenticate=false,ssl=false,port=8291
```

When I tried start the server I received the following error:

`<Mar 21, 2014 4:53:21 PM> <INFO> <NodeManager> <Starting Coherence server with command line: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/java -Dtangosol.coherence.member=coh_server1 -Dtangosol.coherence.wka=127.0.0.1 -Dtangosol.coherence.wka.port=8888 -Dtangosol.coherence.clusterport=7777 -Dtangosol.coherence.clusteraddress=231.1.1.1 -Dtangosol.coherence.ttl=0 -Dtangosol.coherence.localport=8888 -Dtangosol.coherence.localhost=127.0.0.1 -Dtangosol.coherence.cluster=my_coh_cluster -Djava.class.path=/opt/Oracle/Weblogic/12.1.1/coherence_3.7/lib/coherence.jar: /opt/Oracle/Weblogic/12.1.1/modules/javax.management_1.2.2.jar: /opt/Oracle/Weblogic/12.1.1/modules/javax.management.remote_1.0.1.4.jar: /opt/Oracle/Weblogic/12.1.1/coherence_3.7/lib/coherence-web-spi.war: /opt/Oracle/Weblogic/12.1.1/modules/features/weblogic.server.modules.coherence.server_12.1.1.0.jar -Dtangosol.coherence.management.remote=true -Dtangosol.coherence.management=all -Dtangosol.coherence.session.localstorage=true -Dtangosol.coherence.cacheconfig=/opt/Oracle/Weblogic/12.1.1/user_projects/domains/labs_domain/config/coherence/my_coh_cluster/session-cache-config.xml ‐Xmanagement:autodiscovery=false,authenticate=false,ssl=false,port=8291 -Dweblogic.RootDirectory=/opt/Oracle/Weblogic/12.1.1/user_projects/domains/labs_domain weblogic.nodemanager.server.provider.WeblogicCacheServer >
<Mar 21, 2014 4:53:21 PM> <INFO> <NodeManager> <Working directory is '/opt/Oracle/Weblogic/12.1.1/user_projects/domains/labs_domain'>
<Mar 21, 2014 4:53:21 PM> <INFO> <NodeManager> <Server output log file is '/opt/Oracle/Weblogic/12.1.1/user_projects/domains/labs_domain/servers_coherence/coh_server1/logs/coh_server1.out'>
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ‐Xmanagement:autodiscovery=false,authenticate=false,ssl=false,port=8291
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ‐Xmanagement:autodiscovery=false,authenticate=false,ssl=false,port=8291
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: ‐Xmanagement:autodiscovery=false,authenticate=false,ssl=false,port=8291.  Program will exit.
<Mar 21, 2014 4:53:21 PM> <FINEST> <NodeManager> <Waiting for the process to die: null>
<Mar 21, 2014 4:53:21 PM> <INFO> <NodeManager> <Server failed during startup so will not be restarted>
<Mar 21, 2014 4:53:21 PM> <FINEST> <NodeManager> <runMonitor returned, setting finished=true and notifying waiters>`

It seems that ‐Xmanagement:autodiscovery is wrong, I just don't know why, 'cause I just follow the steps

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is you are not pointed at the JRockit JVM, which is the only JVM that will recognize the `Xmanagement:autodiscovery` option.

Right now you're pointed at: `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/java`

Switch your JAVA_HOME to a JRockit install.

The other option is to try `-Dcom.oracle.management.autodiscovery` instead, based on the information here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15062/doptions.htm

Comment: Hi @better_use_mkstemp, I tried use JRockit and the error remains. I also tried use `-Dcom.oracle.management.autodiscovery`, but I got the same error again